# Getting the axis pointing up in a rotation (Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, axis

I have an object in unity which has a rotation described as the following:
x, y, z, where they are both rotations ranging from 0 to 360 around their respective axis.

Now I'm trying to find out which of the vectors point up the most. Essentially I have a 6-sided dice, on which I use physics to emulate a dice-throw. I now want to find out which of the 6 faces of the die points upwards. I can imagine some rather advanced if sentences, revolving around checking the rotations individually, but I'd like to know if there is a good way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the face directions with:

- transform.up
- -transform.up
- transform.right
- -transform.right
- transform.forward
- -transform.forward

You need to associate each direction with the appropriate face value. The side facing up will be the one with the greatest [Dot Product](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Dot.html) vs Vector3.up (the world "up" direction). A dot product of 1 means a face is pointing directly up. Note that this only works because all the directions are unit vectors.

```
Vector3.Dot(Vector3.up, transform.up);
```

Given that it's only 6 (or 3 if you are clever) if statements to find the max that's probably the best way. If you are considering the general case, i.e. to support any die shape and number of faces, you could store a list of structs with a lambda expression denoting the face direction + the face value then use Linq Max().

Comment: Thank you, this was very easy to understand and very easy to implement. Even though I don't need support for other than 6 dice, it's still really nice that you offered advice on this.

It worked like a charm. I'm curious though. How could it be done with 3 if sentences? My code only accesses 3 if sentences, but I did need to use more than that ^^

Comment: Hint: You can take advantage of the fact that -dot(v) == dot(-v) and that opposing sides of a cubic die add up to 7. Therefore you need one if statement per pair of sides, and can calculate the face value using the sign of the dot product and an offset from 7/2. I don't necessarily recommend this as your code is probably more understandable with one 'if' per side.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot for the clarification though! ^^

Answer (score 0):

You could, as you say, check the rotations directly manually.

Here's an alternative collider-based approach: put invisible children game objects with individual trigger colliders on each face of the die, then whenever one of them collides with the table surface, record the number of the opposite side of the face.

Comment: This is a really good idea, and I like the simplicity and creativity, unfortunately I did prefer a mathematical answer, and thus I chose the other one. Still, I would like to thank you a lot for the help! ^^

Comment: @SanderSkovgaardHansen - sure thing. I like the vector math based solution also!